# rar files have same name how to join them

Tags: archiving, winrar

I am trying to download an Android game. The files I downloaded are called:

```
com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftKRHM.part01.rar
com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftKRHM.part02.rar
com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftKRHM.part03.rar
com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftKRHM.part04.rar
```

I can extract the first archive without problems. However, the files stored inside these RAR archives have identical names, so when I try to extract the second archive to same folder, it tells me that a file with same name already exists and ask whether I want to replace the first file or rename the second one.

So, what do I do now? If I replace the file, there's no point in extracting it from the first archive. If I rename it, how can it coexist with the first one?

I tried to search for a solution, but everybody just says that it should be handled automatically. This is not the case.

Comment: I am trying to download an adroid game that is in four parts I have downloaded but into all these four parts the files are of same size as well same name. so I extract first file its done, but when I extract second file to same folder it asks the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files you downloaded are called:

```
com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftKRHM.part01.rar
com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftKRHM.part02.rar
com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftKRHM.part03.rar
com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftKRHM.part04.rar
```

The four files you downloaded form a so-called *multi-part archive*. The game has been stored inside a single archive, which then has been split in four parts. The main reason for this is that downloading four small files is easier than downloading one big file.

The problem you are facing are due to the fact that, when you click on the second archive, you're actually opening the exact same archive for the second time.

You only have to extract the first of them. When you open the first archive in WinRAR (or any other archive manager) and click extract, WinRAR automatically reads all four parts of the archive. You have four archives, but they are treated as they were one.

Comment: dennis, the game data are of 700 mb which are split into four parts. each arechive has about 195 mb. by your answer you mean I need to download all four files but need to extract onlt the one, how is it possible. plz explain, thanx for your patience. this is a big issue faced by many.

Comment: ok gr8, I try it now and shift the data of the extracted files into mt phone and see if it works, will come back in few minutes, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Ok Dennis, its taking a bit of time and perhaps you are right, I need to open just one archieve and file is there, actually it seems rar people have changed something previously the jointing process was bvisible to eyes and hence I thought it shall be done but now it seems they have done it automatically. thnx buddy for your time and god bless you. Anything India related work, do remember me would do anything for you.

Comment: I use to split 700 files in chunks of rar file and when anyone file is open using winrar it joins all videos into one